# JavaScript How to pass a parameter to a function

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing

I am having trouble passing a parameter to a function.

Here is my code (edited to show flow and positioning in the html doc):

```
<!-- this src file precedes -->
    // this resides in a js src file on its own and as is
    function mySpecialFunction(thisIndex) {
      alert(thisIndex); // shows as blank
    }

<!-- this src file follows -->
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {
    $(document).on('change', '.jq__pAC', function(event) {
    var i = 1;
    // some JavaScript code
    mySpecialFunction(i);
    // some more JavaScript code
    }); // end jq__pAC
  }); // end .load()
}); // end .ready()
```

my `alert()` event displays blank.

The 2 blocks of js code are in separate src files. Does that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/k4s46/

Comment: Yeah, there's absolutely nothing wrong with that code. What browser are you using? -- I see they are in different files. Simply include the function before you include the call for it.

Comment: sure does @j08691 -- and even to my "eyeball" I see nothing wrong with it.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the code is in 2 different places, you just need to make sure that the file which defines the function is called first.

Comment: Depends on the order of your JavaScript files.

Comment: chrome latest @NickDugger

Comment: I edited my code to show it's position and some other things that may come into play @APAD1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you say the functions are in different files, probably the order of the files in the problem.

Make sure that the calling method (`mySpecialFunction(i);`) comes after the declaration (`function mySpecialFunction(thisIndex)`).

EDIT:

In your edit you have `$(document).ready` and `$(window).load`. Remove the last one and it will work.

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zq6tR/).

Comment: is javascript not like PHP where the functions can live wherever @PatrickHofman?

Comment: No. It is not. You have to declare it before you use it.

Comment: ok, thanks -- that's probably my problem. I'll check @PatrickHofman

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Well, function declarations are hoisted, so `foo(); function foo() { ... }` will work fine.

Comment: Not if they're in separate files, though. The function itself must be declared before the call, if they reside in separate files.

Comment: @FelixKling: I didn't think so when using multiple files. In the same file it does.

Comment: Yeah, of course not across separate files. I was just referring to your comment.

Comment: I edited my code to show it's position and some other things that may come into play @NickDugger

Comment: ok, thanks @PatrickHofman...something else has to be going on because it still does not work.

Comment: @FelixKling: ah. Okay. Forgot so say 'in this case'.

Comment: @H.Ferrence: did the change inside event fire? When you look at the jsfiddle you will see it works.

Comment: yes it "fired". I am looking into my calling script because somewhere along the way I lose the value for "i". So, in effect, "i" is blank when the call takes places. So sorry to trouble you. But you did help me hone in on the issue a bit closer. @PatrickHofman